# problem with VNC

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, vnc

I upload vnc on my server and when i execute it : winvnc.exe -install i get this error :

> The vnc service could not be installed

what am i going to do ?

Comment: did you use a admin account ?

Comment: You could start by adding more relevant details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system? I assume Windows because of the file name, but it would be helpful to state it; also, which version of Windows?

And, BTW, what VNC are you using? There are *quite* a lot of them around.

Being Windows, a standard question is: do you have Administrator rights on that server?

Also, are you trying to install it on the server's physical console, or using a Remote Desktop connection? Some versions of VNC just don't let you install them over RDP.

Comment: my server is : windows 2003
version vnc : 3.3.7
my account is admin

Comment: What about RDP?

Comment: the rdp port is not listening on my server

Comment: Are you trying to install VNC through a Remote Desktop connection session or through Console Session ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds like it could be caused by the file being blocked by windowns.

```
right click the file and selecting ublock at the bottom of properties screen
```

Now attempt to install again.

**EDIT**
Just seen this is an old question!